# Does a substring search with LIKE benefit from an index?

Tags: indexing, sql-like, hsqldb

Assume the following table definition in HSQLDB:

```
create table message(id varchar(255) primary key not null, data clob not null);
```

Will the index which HSQLDB creates automatically on `id` (being the primary key) speed up a substring search like the following?

```
select * from message where id like 'foo:%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently substring searches do benefit from an index on that column.

Running

```
explain plan for select * from message where id like 'foo:%'
```

gives me

```
…
access=INDEX PRED
…
```

just like for a simple equal sign comparison. This seems to work for any substring, e.g. `'%foo%'`, not just the beginning of a string.

For comparison, if I try the same on the `data` column (which is not indexed and thus requires a full table scan), I get

```
…
access=FULL SCAN
…
```